# Expectations of stopping times in general

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, stopping-times

I have a very basic question: So for a stopping time $\tau$ with $E(\tau)<\infty$ we have $E(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\tau>n)$, right? Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming discrete time, that is just a basic property of expectation. However, you need $\geq$. Break it up into the actual values and see how many each gets repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an usual "trick" :

By definition,

$$E(\tau) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n P( \tau = n)$$

But as

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 $$

you get

$$E(\tau) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 \right) P( \tau = n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  P( \tau = n) \right)$$

Now, you invert both sums

$$E(\tau) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{n=i+1}^{\infty} P( \tau = n)$$

And as the events $\{\tau = n\}$ are disjoints, you have that

$$\sum_{n=i+1}^{\infty} P( \tau = n) = P( \tau > i )$$

Hence the result :

$$E(\tau) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty P( \tau > i )$$

Comment: I  think somewhere before the second equation you should define what the second sum is actually summing up. I don't see any $i$ in the equation, therefore it's a little confusing what's being done at that point.

Comment: I just use the fact that $$ n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 $$. I'll add a step to better show the magic trick ;)